# Daily file archive

Tags: scripts

I am trying to write a shell script that will do the following using cron everyday at midnight:

go into foo directory find all files that start with "CA", compress them and move them to an archive directory as a single time stamped file.  I am using the script below right now, but it is taking the directory structure with it and I don't want the directory structure.  I just want to have one time stamped file of that day with all of that days files compressed inside it.

```
**************current script attempt******************

#!/bin/sh
#
TIME=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
FILENAME=DailyArchive-$TIME.tar.gz
SRCDIR=/foo
DESDIR=/archive
tar -cpzf $( find -name "ca*.pdf" ) $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR

*****************end of script*************************
```

Thanks,
/casey

Comment: Should not you change your command to 'tar -czf $( find "$SRCDIR" -name "ca*.pdf" ) -C "$DESDIR/$FILENAME"'?

Comment: I changed the command to this and received this error:  tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive. I have one file in there that starts with  ca so it wouldn't be an empty archive.

Comment: Run this one alone after setting SRCDIR, echo "$( find "$SRCDIR" -name "ca*.pdf" ) ", to see if it's returning any find file result or not

Comment: it returns one file: /archive/ca12345678.pdf

Comment: Sorry, the command should be this, 'tar -czf "$( find "$SRCDIR" -name "ca*.pdf" )" "$FILENAME" -C "$DESDIR/"'

Comment: I changed it to that and it is producing the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: echo $FILENAME to see variable getting value?

Comment: I ran this: echo "$( find "$SRCDIR" -name "ca*.pdf" )" "$FILENAME" -C "$DESDIR/" and got this DailyPharmArchive-2016-12-05.tar.gz -C /archive

Comment: !! You told me this 'echo "$( find "$SRCDIR" -name "ca*.pdf" )"' return [file name](http://askubuntu.com/questions/857317/daily-file-archive?noredirect=1#comment1320735_857317), so finally it return or not, what is shown in your [this command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/857317/daily-file-archive?noredirect=1#comment1320854_857317), find doesn't return input files for. BTW, this should be work 'tar -czf "$( find "$SRCDIR" -name "ca*.pdf" )" "$FILENAME" -C "$DESDIR/"'